# Creating dynamic calculation rules in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I'm interested in creating dynamic calculation rules in Angular that can be stored in a database for future use. These rules will be applied to employee data to calculate various dynamic fields defined by the user.

Dynamic fields:

```
Basic Salary
OT Hours 1
OT Value 1
OT Hours 2
OT Value 2
OT Amount 1
OT Amount 2
Loan
Salary Advance
Gross Salary
Total Deduction
Net Salary
```

The dynamic fields that will be involved in the calculations.

Calculation rules:

```
[
{field: 'Basic Salary',
expression: 'number',
isCalculate: false},

{field: 'OT Hours 1',
expression: 'number',
isCalculate: false},

{field: 'OT Hours 2',
expression: 'number',
isCalculate: false},

{field: 'OT Value 1',
expression: '((Basic Salary / 26)/8)*1.5',
isCalculate: true},

{field: 'OT Value 2',
expression: '((Basic Salary / 26)/8)*2',
isCalculate: true},

{field: 'OT Amount 1',
expression: 'OT Hours 1 * OT Value 1',
isCalculate: true},

{field: 'OT Amount 2',
expression: 'OT Hours 2 * OT Value 2',
isCalculate: true},

{field: 'Loan',
expression: 'number',
isCalculate: false},

{field: 'Salary Advance',
expression: 'number',
isCalculate: false},

{field: 'Gross Salary',
expression: 'Basic Salary + OT Amount 1 + OT Amount 2',
isCalculate: true},

{field: 'Total Deduction',
expression: 'Loan + Salary Advance',
isCalculate: true},

{field: 'Net Salary',
expression: 'Gross Salary - Total Deduction',
isCalculate: true},

]
```

The calculation rules will be represented as an array of objects. Each object will contain the field name, the calculation expression, and a flag to indicate whether the field needs to be calculated or not.

Later, when a user wants to calculate Salary for employees, the system will evaluate these expressions based on the provided input data and return the results.

Is there an effective way to achieve this functionality in Angular? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course you can. It seems like you want these calculations to be done via the frontend, not calculated on the backend and then passed back to the client.

I would create a plain JS utility function that accepts your array as input and spits out the calculation. Then use an angular component to display these values. It's not clear your project structure so I can only give you generic advice at this point in time without further details.

Comment: "It seems like you want these calculations to be done via the frontend, not calculated on the backend and then passed back to the client".
Exactly this is what I want. Can you please elaborate on your answer a little bit? If you can provide a sample then it would be very useful.

Comment: @Garuuk
 I have a screen to create fields and the rules using those dynamic fields. Users can give any name for the fields. And using those fields user can define the rule. I will store those data in the db.

On another screen, those fields will be shown and accept values from user input. Then at the end, the system will apply the rules on the values and give the results.

For example:
Basic Salary = 1000
OT Hours1 =10

So the results will show OT Amount1 as 72.11 

(i.e. ((1000/26)/8)*1.5*10 Please refer to the calculation rule shown in my question)